# "ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension" on Heroku Aspen

Tags: ruby, heroku, rubygems

I am tring to clone an old Ruby project from one Heroku app to another but I can't get it to run.

I have setup a new app with the aspen-mri-1.8.6 stack.

But when I push the code up (cloned directly from the app that's working), I get the following error:

```
Counting objects: 465, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (214/214), done.
Writing objects: 100% (465/465), 192.12 KiB | 95 KiB/s, done.
Total 465 (delta 239), reused 440 (delta 230)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby/Rack app detected

-----> Installing gem patron from http://rubygems.org
       Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
       ERROR:  Error installing patron:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

       /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
       checking for curl-config... no
       checking for main() in -lcurl... no
       *** extconf.rb failed ***
       Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
       necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
       details.  You may need configuration options.

       Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
        --with-curl-dir
        --without-curl-dir
        --with-curl-include
        --without-curl-include=${curl-dir}/include
        --with-curl-lib
        --without-curl-lib=${curl-dir}/lib
        --with-curllib
        --without-curllib
       extconf.rb:34:   Can't find libcurl or curl/curl.h (RuntimeError)

         Try passing --with-curl-dir or --with-curl-lib and --with-curl-include
         options to extconf.


       Gem files will remain installed in /app/tmp/repo.git/gems_build/gems/patron-0.4.18 for inspection.
       Results logged to /app/tmp/repo.git/gems_build/gems/patron-0.4.18/ext/patron/gem_make.out
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to install gem

To git@heroku.com:thumbify.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:thumbify.git'
```

Any advice would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

> sudo apt-get install libcurl3-dev

---

libcurl is an easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library
and this is one of libraries than mri ruby requires

Comment: Maybe some explanation to accompany the command, for the benefit of future readers?